# Importing & Exporting Calendars Office 365 & Office 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, exchange, calendar

My organization uses Office 365 with exchange; on our workstations we use Office 2016. My question is, I have a user who is leaving our organization and I need to export his calendar and import it into another users calendar. I need this to happen both locally and also in the cloud so all of the events are visible in both the cloud and on his local machine. (so a saved .pst from one PC to another will not work)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the Outlook File -> Open & Export -> Import/Export menu. On the old account, select the "Export to a file" -> "Comma Separated Values" -> select the required Calendar folder and export it to a CSV file. After that you can import the resulting CSV on a new account using the same menu but this time select "Import from another program or file" in the "Import and Export Wizard".

Comment: Will doing this also add the events to the cloud? or will it just add the events locally to the computer?

Comment: Yes, it will sync the local folder to the O365 servers.

Answer (score 0):

If the users are using O365 client(Office 2016), you can export Calendar from user A's mailbox as .PST, then import the /PST file to user B's Outlook 2016 client. It will sync the Calendar to user B's mailbox, and user B can find user A's calendar in his own OWA(it means the imported calendar is not just in local). It works in my environment.

You can have a simple test with different ways before the user left company, then select the method which is most convenient for you. :)